# split string with timestamps

Tags: python, regex, string

Hello i have scraped information from the web and standardized it to remove all html etc leaving me with a single string which contains

```
foo XX:XX +XX:XX bar XX:XX +X:XX bar2 XX:XX +X:XX bar3 XX:XX bar4 XX:XX bar5
```

Where `foo` is not proceeded by a timestamp, keeping or removing `foo` is fine either way as it is always repeated as the first `bar`.

I wish to split on `XX:XX` but **not** on `+XX:XX` , each `bar` can be preceeded by either `XX:XX +XX:XX` or just `XX:XX`

I also wish to keep the timestamp upon splitting so i get a list of strings like:

```
XX:XX +XX:XX bar
XX:XX +XX:XX bar2
.....
XX:XX bar5
```

To help understanding this is based on football match html commentary taken from the bbc website such as http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/0/football/27092972

the regex i am trying to get working as a starting point is

```
(?(name)\d+:\d\d|\+\d+:\d\d)
```

which is wrong considering it wont compile, it is meant to be of the form :

```
(?(id/name)yes-pattern|no-pattern)
```

where the yes pattern is

```
\d+:\d\d (1 or more digits, colon, 2 digits)
```

and the no pattern is

```
+\d+:\d\d (same as yes pattern, but with a + sign proceeding)
```

i will be using `re.split(expression)`

For further information, i am planning on converting the timestamps to seconds later, so i will be added `XX:XX` and `+XX:XX` to `YY:YY` later.

Here is an example string my program currently has

```
Full Time Match ends, Everton 3, Swansea City 1. 90:00 +4:09 Full time Full Time Second Half ends, Everton 3, Swansea City 1. 90:00 +2:47 Attempt blocked. Nathan Dyer (Swansea City) right footed shot from the centre of the box is blocked. Assisted by Pablo HernÃ¡ndez. 90:00 +0:18 Offside, Swansea City. Leroy Lita tries a through ball, but Ashley Williams is caught offside. 89:31 Corner, Swansea City. Conceded by Leighton Baines. 88:42 Foul by James McCarthy (Everton).
```

So i wish to get as a list

```
Full Time Match ends, Everton 3, Swansea City 1.
90:00 +4:09 Full time Full Time Second Half ends, Everton 3, Swansea City 1. 
90:00 +2:47 Attempt blocked. Nathan Dyer (Swansea City) right footed shot from the     centre of the box is blocked. Assisted by Pablo HernÃ¡ndez. 
90:00 +0:18 Offside, Swansea City. Leroy Lita tries a through ball, but Ashley Williams is caught offside. 
89:31 Corner, Swansea City. Conceded by Leighton Baines. 
88:42 Foul by James McCarthy (Everton).
```

Comment: I don't get why in your expected output the `88:42 Fould by ...` is on the same line as `89:31 Corner, ...`. Is that a typo? Or what's the logic behind it? Should that happen for equal timestamps?

Comment: my apologies its a typo i'll fix now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a **Positive Lookahead** here.

```
results = re.split(r'\s+(?=\d+:\d{2})', s)
```

Regular expression:

```
\s+           # whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times)
(?=           # look ahead to see if there is:
 \d+          # digits (0-9) (1 or more times)
 :            # ':'
 \d{2}        # digits (0-9) (2 times)
)             # end of look-ahead
```

Output

```
[
 'Full Time Match ends, Everton 3, Swansea City 1.', 
 '90:00 +4:09 Full time Full Time Second Half ends, Everton 3, Swansea City 1.', 
 '90:00 +2:47 Attempt blocked. Nathan Dyer (Swansea City) right footed shot from the centre of the box is blocked. Assisted by Pablo Hern\xc3\x83\xc2\xa1ndez.', 
 '90:00 +0:18 Offside, Swansea City. Leroy Lita tries a through ball, but Ashley Williams is caught offside.',
 '89:31 Corner, Swansea City. Conceded by Leighton Baines.', 
 '88:42 Foul by James McCarthy (Everton). '
]
```

Comment: Fantastic, works perfectly, as someone who is not that experienced with regex could you explain the `(?=` part, i understand that ? is normally to signify greedy mode but i dont fully understand the regex string.

Thanks a lot for your time

Edit: Saw the addition of positive lookahead, i read and understand it now, so you're saying basically any timestamp which has whitespace before, without discounting anything before the first match, which matches the `\d+:\d{2}`

Thanks!

Comment: Updated with explanation.